# How can I encrypt my Windows 8 laptop?

Tags: windows-8, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I have a UEFI laptop with Windows 8 that has the GPT partition system. How can I do full disk encryption? It has been announced by the TrueCrypt team that they do not support Windows 8/GPT. I'm not particularly interested in shelling out for Windows 8 Pro and BitLocker. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: A free solution would to be stop using a GPT partition

Comment: @ramhound the laptop won't boot from a non-gpt partition. I tried running Linux on it, and it doesn't quite work.

Comment: If it does not boot from a non-GPT solution you did something wrong all it needs is legacy support and there Re to many non-UEFI tools that exist for it not to have a legacy mode

Comment: @Ramhound it's one of those uberlocked down UEFI secure boot machines. Trust me, I've spent 3 *full* (10+ hours of trying each) days over the past month trying.

Comment: What brand and model do you have?

Comment: If you want full-disk encryption, perhaps it's worth shelling out the bucks. If you can't afford it, maybe you don't need it so bad.  Besides you've shown no research effort and this basically boils down to "name me a free product", which is off-topic.

Comment: @techie007 "No research effort"? I have basically said that Truecrypt doesn't support my setup, I'm not particularly interested in Bitlocker for a variety of reasons, and I'm wondering if there are any other options?

Comment: OK, you looked into one product.  You specifically said you're "...not particularly interested in shelling out for...".  Again, (IMO) this is more like a request for a list of alternative products, not an actual problem, and questions such as those are generally off-topic.  But, hey, it take 5 votes to close... :)

Answer (score 1):

[Secure Doc](http://www.winmagic.com/products/full-disk-encryption-for-windows/standalone)

It does Full Disk Encryption, however since I'm not actively using Windows 8 it's difficult to say how well it works. My suggestion is install this in a VM first, and kick the tires. Your mileage may vary.